# AWS AppSync - Queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I'm currently working with AWS AppSync and found a web tutorial. (Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Xbt7VqkJNc)

All in all, it's a nice example for beginners but I have some problems with creating the demonstrated mutation/query of the tutorial.

The issue is that it's not possible to set an individual ID number (for example "12345") because the output is always an auto-generated ID number.
Is there an option to change the config in DynamoDB or is this problem connected with resolvers in AWS AppSync?

---

Code example:

```
mutation createTodo {
    createTodo(input: {
    name:"Get milk",
    completed: false
  }) {
    id}
}

query getTodo {
  getTodo(id: "afda5d05-bad0-4436-9f8b-76e92d1228c3" ) {
    id name completed} }
```

---

Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getTodo": {
      "id": "afda5d05-bad0-4436-9f8b-76e92d1228c3",
      "name": "Get milk",
      "completed": false
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

the example demonstrated in the video was accepting `id`, `name` and `completed` fields in the input. If you want a randomly generated id each time, you can modify your schema to just pass in `name` and `completed` in the query `createTodo`. You would then need to edit your resolver for this query field (you can do this by clicking on the `createTodo` link under the Resolvers section on your Schemas page). You can edit the Request Mapping Template with the following definition, and this way, a random id is generated each time you create a Todo:

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": { "id": { "S": "$util.autoId()"} },
  "attributeValues": {
    "name": { "S": "$context.arguments.name" },
    "completed": { "S": "$context.arguments.completed" }
  }
}
```

If you see line #5 in the above example, we make use of an in-built utility function to generate an autoId: `$util.autoId()`. This enables you to randomly set ids for your Mutations.

You can find this, plus some of our other supported VTL utility functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! But how is it possible to set individual IDs instead of randomly set IDs? (for example "12345" or "00001")

Comment: To be more specific, is it possible to get the same output as shown in the tutorial? (individual IDs like "12345" instead of random IDs like "afda5d05-bad0-4436-9f8b-76e92d1228c3")

Comment: Yes ofcourse, you need to pass this id as a query parameter. Then check your Request Mapping template for your resolver, and ensure that the key is defined this way: `"key": { "id": { "S": "$ctx.args.id"} },`, it should be saved in DynamoDB with that value.